# C# - Variable values changes after it's executed

Tags: c#

Can someone help me with this code?

EDIT: **Path is 2 points that form the last straight last line.**

Basically I want to draw BLUE the last `profundidadePinca` {0 to profundidadePinca} if the path is bigger than it's value and the rest `TubeConfig.OutsideColor` . Otherwise if it's smaller than `profundidadePinca` just draw it `TubeConfig.OutsideColor`;

PROBLEM: It's drawing Blue on top of the `TubeConfig.OutsideColor`

[Image of my 3D view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GWn0.png)

```
 Point3DCollection remaining = new Point3DCollection();

        TubeVisual3D tubeRemain = new TubeVisual3D();
        tubeRemain.Path = new Point3DCollection(finalPointsTube.ToList().GetRange(remain.idxStart, remain.idxEnd - remain.idxStart + 1));
        if (profundidadePinca < (tubeRemain.Path[1].X - tubeRemain.Path[0].X))
        {
            remaining = tubeRemain.Path;              
            tubeRemain.Path[1] = new Point3D(profundidadePinca, tubeRemain.Path[1].Y, tubeRemain.Path[1].Z);
        }
        tubeRemain.Diameter = TubeConfig.Diameter;
        tubeRemain.IsPathClosed = false;
        tubeRemain.IsSectionClosed = false;
        tubeRemain.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(TubeConfig.OutsideColor);
        tubeRemain.Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#1b74c2")));
        Group.Children.Add(tubeRemain);

        if (profundidadePinca < (remaining[1].X - remaining[0].X))
        {
        TubeVisual3D tubeRemainClamp = new TubeVisual3D();

        var tubeEnding = finalPointsTube[remain.idxEnd].X;
        tubeRemainClamp.Path = new Point3DCollection(finalPointsTube.ToList().GetRange(remain.idxStart, remain.idxEnd - remain.idxStart + 1));

        tubeRemainClamp.Path[0] = new Point3D(profundidadePinca, tubeRemainClamp.Path[0].Y, tubeRemainClamp.Path[0].Z);

        tubeRemainClamp.Diameter = TubeConfig.Diameter;
        tubeRemainClamp.IsPathClosed = false;
        tubeRemainClamp.IsSectionClosed = false;
        tubeRemainClamp.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(TubeConfig.OutsideColor);
        tubeRemainClamp.Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(TubeConfig.OutsideColor));
        Group.Children.Add(tubeRemainClamp);
    }
```

One other thing I dont get:

```
 remaining = tubeRemain.Path;              
 tubeRemain.Path[1] = new Point3D(profundidadePinca, tubeRemain.Path[1].Y, tubeRemain.Path[1].Z);
```

I'm trying to save `tubeRemain.Path` before changing it's value. It works but `remaining` **changes value when the second line is executed. What the hell?**

Comment: For the second part: I would assume that it is an assignment by reference, this means `remaining` and `tubeRemain.Path` are the same object. In the second line you change the `tubeRemain.Path` and through the reference the `remaining` object is also changed. Try changing the first line into `remaining = new Point3DCollection(tubeRemain.Path)` or something similar (I am not familiar with this objects or their constructors, so I can't provide exact code for this)

Comment: and how can I avoid that? I need a temporary variable to store it's value.

Comment: I will try. thx